# Класс не содержит конструктор, который принимает аргументы 0

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
ItemClass NewItemDrop = new ItemClass{name = NewItem.name, sprite = spr, stackable = true};
```

помогите пожалуйста, у меня выше приведенная ошибка ItemClass

```
public ItemClass(TileClass _tile)
{
    name = _tile.name;
    sprite = _tile.tileSprites[0];
    stackable = _tile.stackable;
}
```

вот сам класс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас нету конструктора по умолчанию, вы его заменили  своим конструкторам.
Конструктор `public ItemClass(TileClass _tile)` ждёт от вас `TileClass _tile`, но вы ничего в него не передаёте а начинаете присваивать значение. `{name = NewItem.name, sprite = spr, stackable = true};`
Либо удалите конструктор. Либо передавайте в него тип `TileClass _tile` Вот так `ItemClass NewItemDrop = new ItemClass(_tile);`